# В чем отличие bot.polling() от bot.polling(none_stop=True)?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Вот в принципе и вся проблема, всегда  передавал `polling(none_stop=True)`, без этого бот будет выключаться?

Comment: Если ответ является решением, пожалуйста, отметьте его таковым, это поможет другим участникам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После вызова этой функции TeleBot начинает опрашивать серверы Telegram на предмет новых сообщений.

- none_stop: True / False (по умолчанию False) - не прекращать опрос при получении ошибки от серверов Telegram
- interval: True / False (по умолчанию False) - интервал между запросами на опрос.
  *изменение этого параметра снижает время отклика бота.*
- таймаут: целое число (по умолчанию 20) - Тайм-аут в секундах для длительного опроса

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#telebot

Так же имеется `bot.infinity_polling`:

```
def infinity_polling(self, *args, **kwargs):
    while not self.__stop_polling.is_set():
        try:
            self.polling(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            time.sleep(5)
            pass
    logger.info("Break infinity polling")
```

Метод `infinity_polling` нужен только для обхода падения бота путем перезапуска его. В обычной ситуации вызывался бы `bot.polling`, внутри которого также крутился цикл.

Т.к. этот код вызывает цикл, то все остальные действия ниже него не произойдут пока цикл не завершится.

Если нужно параллельно что-то выполнить, то нужно запускать что-то в отдельном потоке, например самого бота -- через вызов `infinity_polling`.

[telebot/**init**.py#L367](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/e62eeb7ff2a6c23f2a30dff38b19d76d62e45eb3/telebot/__init__.py#L367)